# Spring Boot - unable to add JS in a webpage

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple webpage and want to add JS to it.

The controller rendering the page is -

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/testui")
public class GreetingController {

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "pages/greeting";
}
```

}

The struture of my resources folder are  -

```
src/main/resources
|
 -- static
 --templates
   |
    --css
    --js
    --pages
```

The Thymeleaf page is -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

</head>

<body>
Welcome to the future
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

PS - I have also tried -

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js/}"></script>
```

But same problem

Answer (score 4):

The problems is the place where your `css` and `js` folders are, those should be inside of `static` folder.

```
src/main/resources
|
 -- static
   |
    --css
    --js
 --templates
   |
    --pages
```

And in your `*.html` page you can use:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- include css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
</head>

<body>
Welcome to the future
</body>
    <!-- include javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js}"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nope didnt work.. I think i need to register a path in application.properties or have to write a configuration java class registering the location in the path

Comment: i followed the tutorial and added a configuration class (https://memorynotfound.com/adding-static-resources-css-javascript-images-thymeleaf/)

Comment: Basicly all content that needs to be served staticly (such as javascript files) should be placed under the static folder. https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: and also add them using the configuration bean